# Magento e-Commerce cannot generate reports

Tags: ecommerce, magento

Good day,

My magento cannot generate reports from the admin panel. I get the following error:

This report depends on timezone configuration. Once timezone is changed, the lifetime statistics need to be refreshed. Last updated: Oct 21, 2010 3:04:33 PM. To refresh last day's statistics, click here."

I follow the instruction and refresh the statistics, still same problem. I confirmed the timezone is right and didn't change before...

Please help.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your config.xml file in /app/etc/ to see if the timzone field matches what is set in your magento admin. If not, update the config.xml file with the correct time zone.
2. Sales Reports may not be available until you use the Refresh Statistics feature to generate the data necessary for reporting

You can find it under Report>> Refresh Statistics

Simply check off all the statics you need to process, then select the time period you want to refresh for (Lifetime or Last Day) from the “Actions” drop down, and click Submit......

Please refer to this thread in the magento forums if you are still having trouble: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewt.../viewthread/199303/P0/

Answer (score 0):

> Please refer to this thread in the magento forums if you are still having trouble: >[http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewt.../viewthread/199303/P0/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewt.../viewthread/199303/P15/#)

I spent quite a bit of time not working directly on my module to understand why this was happening...others may as well benefit from my time.  I created sample data, products, orders and generating reports to solve this problem.  I posted a very lengthy solution on the Magento site at the URL listed above.

The problem centers around Orders that have NOT been processed and still have a status of "Pending", they will NOT appear in most reports.

In a Nut shell:

> Admin Panel / Sales / Orders ~ will show you **ALL** your orders, regardless of an order's status.  *So you must start here.*

Reports under these menus will **NOT print IF** the order is in **"Pending" status**, *which all orders are until you go in via the Admin panel and change them...*

> Admin Panel / Reports / Sales
>      
> Admin Panel / Reports / Products
>      
> Amdin Panel / Reports / Customers

Please go to the Magento site for more detailed instructions http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewt.../viewthread/199303/P15/# including Refreshing twice and a potential Timezone conflict...how to check to make sure that is not an issue for you.